# User Name Conventions for interfaces

Tags: service, interface, naming-conventions

I have reached a bit of confusion when creating my Services.  I have a User table and Company table in the database.  these tables are exposed via services to the client.

My question is which of the following ways do i use to expose the company name to the client?

```
IUserService
{
    string GetComanyName(stirng username);
}


IComanyService
{
    string GetComanyName(stirng username);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Is the company name part of the user or part of the company? Match up the words in the names.

Comment: The Comany table joins to the User table in the database.  And i want to expose the CompanyName (which is in the company table) via a service.  I already have an IUSerService so wanted to add string GetComanyName(stirng username); However now im thinking of creating a new Interface (IComanyService) and exposing the comanyNAme via that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the second method for exposing the web service, simply because it is more logical. You use the company object to get the company's name and not a user object to get a company's name.